# Pandas groupby not copy data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with this data:

original df data is

[image]

I use the next code to fill PO_NAME column

```
df['PO_NAME'] df.groupby(['DEVICE_ID','PO_ID'], sort=False)['PO_NAME'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()))
```

and it works

[image]

but I use the same code to DEPLOY_EPG column

```
df['DEPLOY_EPG'] = df.groupby(['DEVICE_ID','PO_ID'], sort=False)['DEPLOY_EPG'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
```

but it's not working. Column remains blank and code not report any error

what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are no missing values, but empty strings, so use before your solution:

```
df = df.replace(r'^\s*$',np.nan)
```

Comment: same result. that's not seems to be the problem

Comment: @asegovianot - Is possible convert data to dict like `df = df.to_dict('l')` ? Because it should workinf well.

Comment: in that case groupby not works: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'groupby'`

Comment: @asegovianot - I think before groupby for see data, because this is data related problem